# Certificate in debug log

Tags: apex, security, certificates

We are making a secure (https) service call and including a certificate in the process.  The service provider has stated that they are not receiving the certificate with the service call but we are definitely setting the `clientCertName__x` value to a valid certificate (see code below).  Viewing our debug logs, however, does not show any mention of the certificate.

What I would like to confirm is whether or not the debug logs are supposed to display the certificate.  Is the certificate hidden from the logs for security concerns or is there a problem with how we've attached our certificate?  Note: The `Authorization` and `signatureValue` are both displayed in the logs.

```
public void setSSLSettings() {
        this.clientCertName_x = 'CERT_NAME';    
        this.timeout_x = 120000; 
        this.inputHttpHeaders_x = new Map<String, String>();      
        SignatureHelper helper = new SignatureHelper();
        this.inputHttpHeaders_x.put('Authorization', 'Basic');
        this.inputHttpHeaders_x.put('signatureValue', helper.signMessage('sig'));
    }
```

Comment: What happens if you set the `clientCertName_x` to something that is clearly invalid? It should (ideally) give you an error message along the lines of: "Could not find client cert with dev name: 'CERT_NAME_FOOBAR' specified in clientCertName_x". Are you using a Developer Edition Org to make the callouts? These include more detailed callout logging than sandbox and production orgs.

Comment: We did not have to try using an incorrect cert name.  The service provider provided us the wrong endpoint to use - correcting that allowed us to connect successfully.  My conclusion is that the cert is not printed out in the debug statements.

Comment: glad you got it sorted. Can you add your comment as an answer before so the next person to find the question can easily find the resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My experience is that the certificate is not printed out in the debug statements.